# Why would a gas furnace shut down after 20-30 seconds?

Tags: furnace

I have an 18yo Lennox gas furnace (Modle 23G89). It starts and runs for 20-30 seconds then shuts off. The light blinks in a steady state- no code. Then I removed the filter to guarantee a clogged filter wasn't the culprit. I replaced the flame sensor even though I doubted it. There are no loose, broken or off wires that I can see. All supply and returns vents are open. I took the end off the hose for pressure switch that connects near the inducer, but no change. Other appliances in the house use gas and are operating fine.

I called a repairman and had an appointment  but he never called or showed.
 I could use some advice here.

Comment: If you are sure that the furnace is not throwing any codes then try and jump the R and W terminal of the control board and see if it still happens. If not then your issue is the thermostat.

Comment: it's definitely not throwing any codes. Before I jump out the terminals can you tell me what that does?

Comment: R is 24vac continuous power. W is the heating terminal. When you introduce 24vac to the W terminal it will run the heating cycle just as your thermostat would.

Comment: *I took the end off the hose for pressure switch that connects near the inducer, but no change.* Doesn't that mean your pressure switch and/or inducer is defective? Isn't it odd you even get the gas to turn on with that removed, much less it to run...

Comment: When you say "*It starts and runs for 20-30 seconds*", what exactly do you mean?  Do the burners ignite? Does the inducer motor start? Based on the ignition sequence of most gas fired furnaces. I'm going to guess that if it's only "on" for 20-30 seconds, that the burners do not ignite and the problem is early in the ignition sequence.  You should watch the furnace start, and report everything that happens (include everything you see, and hear).